# Digital clock in Lubuntu 16.04 shows one hour more under CET ZT

Tags: lubuntu, clock, ntpd

The digital clock is synchronized with internet servers, set to Europe/Madrid ZT (i.e. CET), but shows one hour more, at the time of posting this question it is 20:31. I've tried to remove and add it again, no changes. Have browsed for 'ZT=' in configuration user files, nothing shows up. Also run `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`, and this is the answer:

```
24 Jan 20:32:10 ntpdate[15050]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

Have no clue of what to do, since another laptop (same brand, model and configuration: HP ProBook 6360b, 16GB, 250GB SSD) was installed at the same time, and it shows the right time, at home under a private router; while this one is in a public institution. Both have Lubuntu 16.04 installed, alone.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of being in the network of a public institution made a difference. Port 123 (used by default to synchronize) was closed, so using the `-u` (which contacts the ntp server through an unprivileged port) was the solution:

```
$sudo ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
26 Jan 10:03:48 ntpdate[5080]: adjust time server 158.227.98.15 offset 0.005423 sec
```

and now the correct time is showing in the panel.